# Is this a bug in Java.Calendar in Linux? Year not updated

Tags: java, linux, calendar

I've got something strange happening in a server running Linux, while a windows machine performing the same code behaves normally.

It is happening with the following code:

```
    public static final SimpleDateFormat sqlDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("Y-M-d");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String now = sqlDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(now);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -4);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    String trsh = sqlDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(trsh);
```

The output on the windows machine running:

```
    java version "1.7.0_07"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

    Output:
    2014-01-02
    2013-12-29
```

The above is matching the expected result.

The output on the Linux machine running:

```
    java version "1.8.0-ea"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)

    Output:
    2014-01-02
    2014-12-29
```

This is odd isn't it? Any nice workarounds?

Comment: Sun Dec 29 00:00:30 IST 2013
1.8.0-ea
Mac OS X
`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -4);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));`

Comment: That is odd. Perhaps a stupid point, but try subtracting a second or two as well - does that make any difference? I ran into a bug a long while back that was similar to this, and for some bizarre reason that was a workaround... long shot I admit.

Comment: So it seems to be working fine on Mac OS X. Isn't OS X using the same library's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you have constructed your format object with pattern symbol Y instead of y. Y stands for year of weekdate, not the normal iso calendar year. It is locale-dependent, especially dependent on when the week starts. So the locale settings on your windows machine and the linux server might be different. Remember that java.util.Calendar IS dependent on locale, too.

Try `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Wow thanks, that is a nice catch! this solves the issue! This also explains why the problem did not yet arrise yesterday...

Comment: @BasGoossen: a good rule of thumb: when you think it's a bug in Java the odds greatly favor that it's really a bug in your understanding of Java. This rule works well for me, and should work well for you. And by odds, I'm talking 1000000 to 1 or more. Seriously.

Comment: @Hovercraft: You are right, i already added a questionmark to the bug note. Never even thought of the locale settings. Checked the system time twice but forgot the locale.

Answer (score 5):

You have a wrong format for a year in a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You should be using `y` instead of `Y`.